# Make the pivot's header align center

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I've try to make the header of pivot stay at center (in image, head1 was align left). I try to change the style of pivot but it didn't work.

Here's the custom style ( I tried to add `HorizontalAlignment="Center"` to every where related to the header of pivot, but neither of them worked )

```
    <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Key="ItemsPanelTemplate1">
        <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    <Style x:Key="PivotHeaderItemStyle1" TargetType="Primitives:PivotHeaderItem">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="21,0,1,0"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Primitives:PivotHeaderItem">
                    <Grid>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unselected"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Opacity="{StaticResource PhonePivotUnselectedItemOpacity}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>


    <Style x:Key="PivotStyle1" TargetType="phone:Pivot">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="phone:Pivot">
                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Grid.RowSpan="3"/>
                        <ContentControl ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding TitleTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Title}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="24,17,0,-7" Style="{StaticResource PivotTitleStyle}"/>
                        <Primitives:PivotHeadersControl x:Name="HeadersListElement" Grid.Row="1" ItemsPanel="{StaticResource ItemsPanelTemplate1}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource PivotHeaderItemStyle1}" />
                        <ItemsPresenter x:Name="PivotItemPresenter" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Grid.Row="2"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

And in Page.xaml:

```
        <phone:Pivot Style="{StaticResource PivotStyle1}">
            <phone:PivotItem x:Name="head1">
                <phone:PivotItem.Header>
                    <TextBlock Text="head1" FontSize="30" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                </phone:PivotItem.Header>
                <Grid/>
            </phone:PivotItem>
            <phone:PivotItem x:Name="head2">
                <phone:PivotItem.Header>
                    <TextBlock Text="head2" FontSize="30" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                </phone:PivotItem.Header>
            </phone:PivotItem>
            <phone:PivotItem x:Name="head3">
                <phone:PivotItem.Header>
                    <TextBlock Text="head3" FontSize="30" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                </phone:PivotItem.Header>
            </phone:PivotItem>
            <phone:PivotItem x:Name="head4">
                <phone:PivotItem.Header>
                    <TextBlock Text="head4" FontSize="30" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                </phone:PivotItem.Header>
            </phone:PivotItem>
            <phone:PivotItem x:Name="head5">
                <phone:PivotItem.Header>
                    <TextBlock Text="head5" FontSize="30" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                </phone:PivotItem.Header>
            </phone:PivotItem>
        </phone:Pivot>
```

[image: Is there a way to make the selected pivot header align center in horizontal ?]

Comment: The "problem" is that all the head elements are only taking up exactly as much space as they need. It doesn't matter if you align it differently since it's already perfectly aligned in all directions.
Have you tried changing the size of the textblock which contains the 'head1' label? If you do you should be able to see some change.
(I might be wrong, haven't tested yet)

Comment: Center in the sense? You mean of the page?

Comment: @Kulasangar yes, for example in the image I posted, "head1" must between all the "head" ( head4, head5 in the left, head2, head3 in the right, i think)